# How to use exception handling in Django view

Tags: django, django-models, exception, django-forms

Suppose i have this code

```
if form.is_valid(): 
   form.save()
```

Now suppose my form is valid i have exception that foregin key value is linked to more than one column so it will raise exception

Now i want to know is there any way to grab that exception value and pass to jquery via AJAX

Because form is valid so it comes inside the loop but its not able to go after `form.save`

So how can i program that if exception occurs it get passed to jquery like

```
if exception
   return HttpResponse(exception)
```

I get this exception

> MultipleObjectsReturned at
>   /manage/Source/create/   get() returned
>   more than one Account -- it returned
>   3! Lookup parameters were
>   {'account_number':
>   u'121121'}

What type of exception it is

Comment: [Really?](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: But i don't know what type of exception is there , can i catch all type of exceptions and put value in variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultipleObjectsReturned **is** the exception.

```
try:
    #do something
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
    return HttpResponse('MultipleObjectsReturned')
```

I wouldn't recommend using a bare try/except to catch all exceptions, as you won't know exactly what's wrong.