# Which file is used in import statement for 'MultipleObjectsReturne' exception

Tags: python, exception

I am using this code

```
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
    return HttpResponse('some error')
```

but i get this error

`global name 'MultipleObjectsReturned' is not defined`

Comment: We don't know. You could create a file with whatever name you like, define `class MultipleObjectsReturned(Exception): pass`, import that file and call it a day. It won't work because it'll have to be the class the code throwing the exception used, but only you know what your `try` is doing and where the code that may throw the exception comes from. "Details" matter.

Comment: Can you point out where you found this example, so that we may vandalize `^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H` fix the example to have a proper namespace?

Comment: It was from my own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622149/how-to-use-exception-handling-in-django-view

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do either:

```
from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned

except MultipleObjectsReturned as e:
    return HttpResponse(e)
```

Or:

```
except yourmodel.MultipleObjectsReturned as e:
    return HttpResponse(e)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned

> A base version of this exception is
>   provided in `django.core.exceptions`;
>   each model class contains a subclassed
>   version that can be used to identify
>   the specific object type that has
>   returned multiple objects.

Comment: Thanks mate delnan comment confused me before but it was simple

Comment: HttpResponse(e.value) is not working but HttpResponse(e) is working

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned
```